# Cucumber-JVM: Cucumber's @After hook is executed twice

Tags: testng, cucumber-jvm

I'm implementing Cucumber Testng for learning purposes. I've realized that the @After hook method is executed twice. I can confirm it with debugging set and a test report output. I only run 1 feature file and my test report shows two entries with identical class names.

Does anyone know why?

[image]

Code:

```
@After
    public void tearDown(Scenario scen) throws IOException {
        ExtentTest logger = reportMgr.getLogger();
        String feature = getClass().getName() + " Feature";    //+ "." + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().toString();

        logger = reportMgr.getExtent().createTest(feature);

        String screenShot = CaptureScreenshot.captureScreen(WebDriverManager.driver, CaptureScreenshot.generateFileName(feature));
        if (!scen.isFailed()) {
            logger.pass("Pass");
            logger.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot);
        } else {
            logger.fail("Fail");
            logger.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot);
        }
    }
```

Feature File:

```
@Login_Valid Feature: Login to Volare Collector Description:  As a user, I want login to Volare Collector 

  Scenario: Valid Login
    Given Volare Collector Home Page opens in browser
    When I login to Volare Collector with Username and Password
    Then Page navigate to Volare Collector Home Page
```

There is warning in the feature file called Multiple Definitions "Volare Collector Home Page opens in browser".

Please download my source code from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wvqczqa99j0ael/Cucumber_TestNG.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Add the feature file also. Are there two scenarios in this feature file?

Comment: Only one scenario in the feature file but there is warning about multiple definitions for  "Volare Collector Home Page opens in browser".

Comment: You should only have an unique definition for a step. Strange you are not getting an exception also.

Comment: Are you sure that you only have one \@After hook defined? Each \@After hook is executed so if you have two, each one gets executed. Post all of your code.

Comment: Please download source code from the link above.

Comment: just use @AfterClass annotation it will run when test ends

Answer (score 3):

`testng.xml` calls the `TestRunner` class. In the `cucumberoptions` there is **no** `tags option`, therefore no filtering based on tags. Thus it will **pick up all the feature files** in the folder given in `features` option - `"src/Features"` ie. Login.feature and Logout.feature.

Each of the feature files has **one scenario each**. Therefore there are **2 scenarios in total** and thus 2 tests will be run. This explains why you see **2 tests in the report**.

When each scenario runs, they will run any present `Before and After hooks`. So for **2 scenarios, hooks will be run twice**.

Also hooks are **global** in nature ie, as long they are present in any classes in the option defined in `glue(glue = {"Step_Definitions"})` they will be picked up. In your case you have **two Before hooks** in Login and Logout classes, you may want to look at fixing that. Use a Before hook and pass it a tag filter in the value option.

In the **single After hook** defined in the `Login` class this piece of code

```
String feature = getClass().getName();          
logger = reportMgr.getExtent().createTest(feature);
```

This means that **name of the test will always be the full class name** ie. `Step_Definitions.Login`. Therefore it shows up as **2 tests with same names although they are different**.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using TestNG 6.8 or higher

Use the following Test class template and check if you have the issue

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

class PlaygroundTest {

  @BeforeClass
  public void setUp(){

  }

  @AfterClass
  public void tearDown() {

  }

  @Test
  public void test(){

  }
}
```